# Find the default separator height of UICollectionView

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

Find the default separator height of UICollectionView. I couldnt find any where what is the height of this separator.

by default UICollectionView is adding some space between the cells verticaclly. I want to know this vertical space height.

Comment: in stroryboard, select your collectionView and then goto size inspector, There you got min spacing lines and cells.

Answer (score 0):

The sperator height of table view or collection view is 1 pixel.
You can get this pixel like following:

```
let separatorHeight = 1/UIScreen.main.scale
```